# How to obtain the plaintext after encoding to utf-8?

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, utf-8

I'm using TCP connection to send data through SOCKET. I succeed in doing that by encoding to utf-8. However, the received message appears as `b'Hello World!'` while the original message is `Hello World!`. Without encoding I get `TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface`. How can I resolve this issue?

Server.py

```
import socket

serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serversocket.bind(('localhost', 8089))
serversocket.listen(5) # become a server socket, maximum 5 connections

while True:
    connection, address = serversocket.accept()
    buf = connection.recv(64)
    if len(buf) > 0:
        print(buf)
        break
```

Client.py

```
import socket

clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientsocket.connect(('localhost', 8089))
x = 'Hello World!'
clientsocket.send(x.encode('UTF-8'))
```

Answer (score 1):

`b'Hello World!'` means that you've received bytes. Instead of encoding you should decode it:

```
>>> b'Hello World!'.decode('utf-8')
'Hello World!'
```

This will convert the bytes to a string using the UTF-8 encoding. In summary:

- Encoding = converting string to bytes using a given encoding
- Decoding = converting bytes to string using a given encoding